# ¿Como puedo hacer para que me funcione el algoritmo de ordenamiento por selección?

Tags: javascript

He realizado el algortimo de ordenamiento por selección, pero no consigo que el algoritmo recorra todo el array. ¿Podrían ayudarme a encontrar el fallo en mi código?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="alg"></h2>
</body>
<script>

function num(arr) {
        var leng = arr.length,
            i, x;
    for( i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
        for( x = i + 1; x < leng; x++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[x]) {
                a(arr, i, x);
            }
        }
    }
}
function a(arr, f, s) {
    var temp = arr[f];
    arr[f] = arr[s];
    arr[s] = temp;   
}
document.getElementById("alg").innerHTML = num([8, 5, 2, 6, 9, 3, 1, 4, 0, 7]);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: La pregunta esta algo incompleta; ¿Que es lo que sucede y que es lo que crees que debería de suceder?¿Donde llamas a `num(arr)` y con que valor?

Comment: @MikelFerreiro ya está editada la pregunta, gracias

Comment: No entiendo bien cual es el problema. Te he puesto una solución al problema que tenías en el código y el algoritmo está bien planteado, recorre todo el array, lo ordena adecuadamente y lo pinta en pantalla. ¿Qué es lo que dices que funciona mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="alg"></h2>
</body>
<script>

function num(arr) {
        var leng = arr.length,
            i, x;
    for( i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
        for( x = i + 1; x < leng; x++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[x]) {
                a(arr, i, x);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return arr;
}
function a(arr, f, s) {
    var temp = arr[f];
    arr[f] = arr[s];
    arr[s] = temp;   
}
document.getElementById("alg").innerHTML = num([8, 5, 2, 6, 9, 3, 1, 4, 0, 7]);
</script>
</html>
```

El problema que tenías es que la función `num()` no devuelve nada, por lo que cuando la llamas para pintar su resultado en el **HTML** estás tratando de imprimir por pantalla algo que no está definido. Para solucionarlo basta con que dicha función devuelva el `array` ordenado al final del bucle.